# Torify + Whois don't work ;(

Tags: linux, socks, torsocks

as i wrote in title. Typing in command:

> **torify whois ****.com**

Output:

> [Mar 04 01:29:26] PERROR torsocks[21980]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:185)
>   getaddrinfo(whois.dns.pl): Non-recoverable failure in name resolution

I also tryed with sudo, torsocks and others domain, but it gives the same output.I'm using manjaro. Thank for helo if anybody would help me :)

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Torsocks: 2.1.0
Whois: Version 5.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try [proxychains](http://www.picateshackz.com/2015/05/kali-linux-tutorial-setting-up.html) - this will help you, I suppose. The tutorial I linked to is not deep-through, but it will help you start